# How to get a callback every time faceid/touchid authentication fails

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, touch-id, face-id

We have a requirement where we have to block the user for 24 hours if Face ID or Touch ID fails for 5 consecutive time.

In Face ID, I am using the fallback to call authentication manager again, and after total of 6 attempts (2 in each call), I block the user in the fallback method itself.

In Touch ID, on third failure, I get a call back to Authentication failed. I call authentication manager again, and on 5th try, I get a call back to Lockout in which I can block the user.

Is there any way common in both Face ID and Touch ID where I can get a callback after every single individual failure so that I can block the user on 5th failure itself?

```
//MARK:- Check if user has valid biometry, if yes, validate, else, show error
fileprivate func biometricAuthentication(completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> ())){
    //        addBlurredBackground()
    //Check if device have Biometric sensor
    if biometryRetryCount == 2 {
        authenticationContext.localizedFallbackTitle = "Ok"
    } else {
        authenticationContext.localizedFallbackTitle = "Retry"
    }

    let isValidSensor : Bool = authenticationContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error)

    if isValidSensor {
        //Device have BiometricSensor
        authenticationContext.evaluatePolicy(
            .deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics,
            localizedReason:  biometryRetryCount == 2 ? "You have been blocked from using the application for next 24 hours. Please come back later" : "Touch / Face ID authentication",
            reply: { [unowned self] (success, error) -> Void in

                if(success) {
                    // Touch or Face ID recognized
                    //                        self.removeBlurredBackground()
                    completion(true)
                } else {
                    //If not recognized then
                    if let error = error {
                        let msgAndAction = self.errorMessage(errorCode: error._code)
                        if msgAndAction.0 != "" {
                            UIApplication.topViewController()?.showAlert(withTitle: "Error", andMessage: msgAndAction.0, andActions: msgAndAction.1)
                        }
                    }
                    completion(false)
                }
        })
    } else {
        let msgAndAction = self.errorMessage(errorCode: (error?._code)!)
        if msgAndAction.0 != ""{
            UIApplication.topViewController()?.showAlert(withTitle: "Error", andMessage: msgAndAction.0, andActions: msgAndAction.1)
        }
    }

}
```

The error methods:

```
//MARK: TouchID error
fileprivate func errorMessage(errorCode:Int) -> (strMessage: String, action: [UIAlertAction]){

    var strMessage = ""
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction.init(title:  Const.Localize.Common().kCancel, style: .cancel) { (cancelAction) in
    }
    var actions: [UIAlertAction] = [cancelAction]

    switch errorCode {

    case LAError.Code.authenticationFailed.rawValue:
        biometricAuthentication { (success) in
            //
        }
    case LAError.Code.userCancel.rawValue:
        if biometryRetryCount == 2 {
            blockUserFor24Hours()
        } else {
            showAlertOnCancelTapAction()
        }
    case LAError.Code.passcodeNotSet.rawValue:
        strMessage = "Please goto the Settings & Turn On Passcode"
    case LAError.Code.userFallback.rawValue:
        biometryRetryCount -= 2
        if biometryRetryCount == 0 {
            blockUserFor24Hours()
        } else {
            biometricAuthentication { (success) in
                //
            }
        }
    default:
        strMessage = evaluatePolicyFailErrorMessageForLA(errorCode: errorCode).strMessage
        actions = evaluatePolicyFailErrorMessageForLA(errorCode: errorCode).action
    }

    return (strMessage, actions)
}


func evaluatePolicyFailErrorMessageForLA(errorCode: Int) -> (strMessage: String, action: [UIAlertAction]){
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction.init(title:  Const.Localize.Common().kCancel, style: .cancel) { (cancelAction) in
    }
    var actions: [UIAlertAction] = [cancelAction]

    var message = ""
    if #available(iOS 11.0, macOS 10.13, *) {
        switch errorCode {
        case LAError.biometryNotAvailable.rawValue:
            message = "Authentication could not start because the device does not support biometric authentication."

        case LAError.biometryLockout.rawValue:
            showPasscodeScreen()

        case LAError.biometryNotEnrolled.rawValue:
            message = "You do not have a registered biometric authentication. Kindly go to the settings and setup one"
            let settingsAction = UIAlertAction.init(title:  Const.Localize.Common().kSetting, style: .default) { (settingsAction) in
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
            }
            actions.append(settingsAction)

        default:
            message = "Did not find error code on LAError object"
        }
    } else {
        switch errorCode {
        case LAError.touchIDLockout.rawValue:
            showPasscodeScreen()
        case LAError.touchIDNotAvailable.rawValue:
            message = "TouchID is not available on the device"
        case LAError.touchIDNotEnrolled.rawValue:
            message = "You do not have a registered biometric authentication. Kindly go to the settings and setup one"
            let settingsAction = UIAlertAction.init(title:  Const.Localize.Common().kSetting, style: .default) { (settingsAction) in
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
            }
            actions.append(settingsAction)

        default:
            message = "Did not find error code on LAError object"
        }
    }

    return (message, actions)
}
```

Comment: On a device, either you will have FaceID or TouchID so what do you mean by common callback?

Comment: I want to avoid writing logic for two different scenarios. See right now, I am blocking on 6 Face ID failures and 5 Touch ID failures. I want to explore possibility of having common 5 failures.